# Looking for a function that fits these characteristics

Tags: functions

So, while going through some numerical data, I find that the analytical solution corresponding to this data displays certain characteristics:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 1$$

and $f(x) \sim x$, when $x \ll 1$

I would like to find functions that would fit these characteristics.

EDIT: I removed one of the conditions, since I later realized I'd made an error. There's also some more information that may be helpful.

The value of f(x) is always less than x, even when x << 1.

f(x) is not oscillatory in any way. It's value does, however, overshoot above f(x)=1 at x=4.6, and then settles down to 1 as x tends to infinity.

Comment: Your description is contradictory. If $f(x)\approx x$ for $x<<1$, then, by definition, $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ must be equal to $0$, because $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ depends on the values of $f(x)$ for **small nonzero** values of $x$.

Comment: What do you mean by $x\ll 1$?

Comment: @5xum Oh my, I just realized a mistake in my reasoning, and turns out that condition is wrong. I'll edit my question to fix that.

Comment: @lulu - roughly x=0.1 and lower. Above that point, the deviation becomes more significant.

Comment: But then your conditions are contradictory.  $f(x)$ can not both be well approximated by $x$ near $0$ and approach $1$.

Comment: @lulu - Yeah, that was an error on my part, I edied the question to remove that.

Comment: The [Logistic function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_function) tends to look like what you want, I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best choice is something like $f_0$, tending both to $\lim_{x \to 0}f_0(x)=x$ and $\lim_{x \to 0}f_0(x)=1$:
$$
f_0(x)=1-e^{-x}
$$

For the overshoot, a good choice *could* be adding the $f_1(x)$ term, which has $\lim_{x \to 0}f_1(x)=0$ and $\frac d {dx}f_1(0)=0$. Good values are $b=0.1$ and $a=0.4$ for an overshoot close to $x=5$:
$$
f_1(x)=bx^2e^{-ax}
$$

The whole function would be $f(x)=f_0(x)+f_1(x).$
[image]